# @RequestParam fails with HttpServletRequestWrapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a standard Spring MVC controller (that services REST calls) like so:

```
@Controller
public class SpringRestController {
    @RequestMapping({"/message"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Message getMessage(@RequestParam(required=false) String username, HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new Message("Hello " + username);
    }
}
```

My understanding is Spring MVC will invoke HttpServletRequest.getParameter("username") and inject the result into the "username" method parameter.

But my original request does *not* contain a "username" parameter. I lookup another request parameter, construct a "username" value and set it in a HttpServletRequestWrapper implementation (using a custom filter). Like so:

```
public class UserResolvingFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filternChain.doFilter(
            new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
                @Override
                public String getParameter(String name) {
                    return getParameterMap().get(name);
                }
                @Override
                public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
                    Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap(super.getParameterMap());
                    // Simplified for brevity
                    map.put("username", new String[] {"testUserName"});
                    return map;
                }                   

            },
            response
        );
    }
}
```

The Filter is configured in web.xml like so:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>userResolvingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>my.package.UserResolvingFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>userResolvingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The issue: The username parameter in my getMessage controller method is always null. I have confirmed that

1. The filter is successfully invoked.
2. Spring invokes my anonymous implementation of HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParameter(String name) with a couple of other parameter names but never with "username".
3. Spring does *not* invoke my anonymous implementation of    HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParameterMap(). Not sure if it should.
4. The "request" parameter (in getMessage() method) is an instance of
   HttpServletRequestWrapper.

I am wondering what could be going wrong?

Note: I have presented only the relevant code with slight modifications to keep the question simple. Please disregard syntactic errors, if any.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised the code compiles.
From the code presented

`return getParameterMap().get(name);`

should be returning a String[] yet the method containing that code is returning a String.

I could be missing something though.